# Unable to create pods on new ansible install

Tags: openshift-origin

All pods created have the following error

> Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "POD" with ErrImagePull: "Tag v1.2.0-1-g7386b49 not found in repository docker.io/openshift/origin-pod"

oc v1.2.0-1-g7386b49

kubernetes v1.2.0-36-g4a3f9c5

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just installed OpenShift origin using the [ansible](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible) installer. The version of the newest installation (at the moment) is `v1.2.0-1-g7386b49`. When you try to start pods and container, openshift origin will pull its images from [here](https://hub.docker.com/u/openshift/) (by default).
Like you can see the images have tags which are similar with `oc versions`.

```
v1.3.0-alpha.0
2 MB
2 months ago
v1.2.0-rc2
2 MB
...
```

OpenShift Origin will try to pull the necessary images based on the version of you installation so it will try to pull images with tag `v1.2.0-1-g7386b49` which doesn't exist.
There are some issues about this on github. It will be fixed soon.
When you want to deploy your pods/containers at the moment your able to use a workaround: Edit your deploymentconfig and edit the image tag to pull from images which exists:

So search your dc config:
oc get dc

```
NAME              REVISION   REPLICAS   TRIGGERED BY
docker-registry   6          1          config
router            1          1          config
```

Edit your dc config:

```
oc edit dc router
```

Edit the following line:

```
image: openshift/origin-haproxy-router:v1.2.0-1-g7386b49
```

To: `image: openshift/origin-haproxy-router:v1.2.0-1`

Maybe you're also able to change the master-config.yaml and edit:

```
imageConfig:
  format: docker.io/openshift/origin-${component}:${version}
```

to

```
imageConfig:
  format: docker.io/openshift/origin-${component}:v1.2.0
```

But I wasn't able to test it. I think this will fixed pretty soon:

Github issue(s): https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/9315

Answer (score 0):

Hello i solved editing master-config.yml , node.yml on each node 
changing latest from false to true!!
It's working